Potentiometer controlled current source with dead zone
I'm working on a current source (for LED). My first iteration circuit works pretty good, but the customer is not happy with the fact the LED is still slightly on when the potentiometer is 0 :

I think it's due to the fact the potentiometer they use does not go to 0. I'm surprised though this bad precision of the pot is not compensated by the offset of the U2.2 :
$$
i^{min} = - V_{FB}^{max} \cdot R = - R \cdot (V_{REF}^{max} + V_{OS})
$$
so
$$
i^{min} > 0 \Leftrightarrow V_{REF}^{max} + V_{OS} < 0 \Leftrightarrow V_{REF}^{max} < -V_{OS} = -1.6mV \text{(i.e. 2.3% of FS = 47/3347x(-5V) = -70mV)}
$$
Thus I thought about adding a diode to create a so called dead-zone on the pot :

My question are :

Could you confirm my dead-zone design will work as espected ? (creating a 500mV/5V = 10% dead-zone at the beginning of the pot) ?
Could you confirm the offset of the opamp U2.1 is working in the way I described ?
Any other advice ?

Thanks!

Why are your schematics split into seven and nine parts with no interconnections? Reading and searching for net names is much more difficult than following a line. Connect everything up and, if it will help understanding the schema, draw dashed-line boxes around each section. 
